# Specifying a command line for Windbg's Open Executable

Tags: windbg

When I use Windbg's "Open Executable..." functionality to use Windbg to step through an executable's execution, is it possible for me to specify command line parameters to be used when running the executable?  If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's an arguments text box available in the Open Executable dialog that can be filled in with any arguments you want to pass to the executable.

[image]

Comment: So basically the answer is to "not be an idiot and look more closely before asking in SO". :(  Hopefully this is useful for others who miss what's right in front of them.

Comment: I missed it too.  It's a modification on a common dialog and as such is easy to overlook, IMO.

Comment: Exactly, I just assume it won’t be there

Comment: Using that Arguments box only lets me put up to 518 characters of my arguments in. How do I input a bigger arguments?

Comment: How do I input non-printable characters?