# Specifying a command line longer than 518 characters in windbg’s Open Executable

Tags: windbg

I opened windbg and use the Open Executable option to open my executable. I have command line parameters that I need to pass to my executable to get it to crash. However, when I tried inputting them to [the Arguments box in the Open Executable dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729542/429091), it won’t let me put more than 518 characters in:

[image: Open Executable dialog’s Arguments box]

How do I start my command with arguments set to a string longer than 518 characters?

I am using WinDbg 10.0.17134.12 AMD64.

Comment: For now I am working around by using WinDbg Preview which doesn’t limit the number of characters I can enter into the Arguments box.

Comment: Did you tried to start it though the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-command-line-options) rather than the GUI? It might be an engine limitation, not a GUI one though.

Comment: @Neitsa When I try to launch with `CMD` I hit its line length limitation and, due to other parameters, can only put about 8040 character of the arguments I want. Isn’t there some way to set it using a command from within windbg itself?

Comment: hmm yes according to [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) the limit is 8191 chars. I'm not aware of any command to change the args once the program is already started. I see 2 options: 1) write a prog to start your program, passing all needed args, then debug it, and make sure you checked "debug child processes also"). 2) change the args through `PEB.ProcessParameters` which holds the program args (not very convenient).

Comment: @Neitsa I was hoping that I could write a command in windbg’s own prompt to set the executable and its command line. I think an explanation of how to use `PEB.ProcessParameters` would be a valid, if inconvenient, answer if you provided details step-by-step instructions and an example ;-).

Answer (score 1):

can you run the executable standalone with arbitrary length of string as argument ?  i doubt it  .

%PATH% can also not exceed certain length

anyway take a look at these globals in kernelbase system dll

these hold the commandline argv[0] to argv[n]

the buffer (unicode or ansi) is allocated in heap

may be you could try swapping the address to some other memory that points to your arbitrary string

```
0:000> ds KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine
004c5b18  "cmdarg.exe aaaaaaaaaaa"
0:000> dS KERNELBASE!BaseUnicodeCommandLine
004c511c  "cmdarg.exe aaaaaaaaaaa"




:\>cat cmdarg.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
void main (int , char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n" , argv[1]);
}
:\>cmdarg.exe
(null)

:\>cmdarg.exe a
a

:\>cmdarg.exe aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

:\>windbg cmdarg.exe aaaa
```

and some thing like this in windbg

i have no idea if this can work on your specific scenerio 
also thie global is used only if GetCommandline variant is used 
not sure if crt uses it internally havent checked it

```
0:000> ? cmdarg
Evaluate expression: 19333120 = 01270000
0:000> ds KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine
002d5b08  "cmdarg.exe aaaa"
0:000> db KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine l8
759c4788  0f 00 10 00 08 5b 2d 00                          .....[-.
0:000> eb KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine
759c4788 0f fe
fe
759c4789 00 00
00
759c478a 10 ff
ff
759c478b 00 00
00
759c478c 08 00
00
759c478d 5b 03
03
759c478e 2d 27
27
759c478f 00 01
01
759c4790 20 

0:000> db KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine l8
759c4788  fe 00 ff 00 00 03 27 01                          ......'.
0:000> ds KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine
01270300  ""
0:000> eza 1270300 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
0:000> ds KERNELBASE!BaseAnsiCommandLine
01270300  "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
01270320  "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
01270340  "aaaaaaaaaa"
```